# Права всех пользователей в Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня на моем сервере имеется огромное количество пользователей. Из них какие-то активные и какие-то не активные, какие именно не известно. Можно ли получить с помощью SQL запроса, права всех пользователей? К примеру: у кого какие права к каким базам.

Microsoft SQL 2015

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй этот запрос:

```
select * from master.sys.server_principals
```